# 'libsoda.so' error when enabling Google Chrome's Live Caption feature

Tags: security, google-chrome, gatekeeper, macos

Since the most recent version of Google Chrome (100.0.4896.127) on macOS Monterey, trying to use Live Caption (chrome://settings/accessibility) results in an error dialog:

"libsoda.so" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software."

Live Caption then indicates that it is not available on sources that previously worked.

This error has been noted on both Intel and Apple Silicon devices.

How can this feature be re-enabled?

Answer (score 7):

Open a new Terminal window (shell) and run the following:

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/SODA/*/SODAFiles/libsoda.so
```

`xattr` is the built-in command to change extended attributes.  The `-dr` flags indicate to recursively delete the specified key; `com.apple.quarantine` is the key that, when enabled/present, triggers the security dialog.

Testing the above with Google Chrome v100 (latest) on Monterey 12.3.1 resolves the `libsoda` error, and Live Caption appears to work normally.

Answer (score 2):

As per 2023-03-24 the path has changed again. This worked for me: `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/SODA/1.1.1.5/SODAFiles/libsoda.so`

Comment: This should be an edit to the answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/439949/237

Comment: @mmmmmm, this is fine as a stand-alone answer. An edit would make info relevant to users of older  versions looking for this info impossible to find.

Comment: @allan both works, but there isn't a lot of value in adding a new answer each time the version number changes :-)  I've edited the original answer to make it work with any version (as long as the path remains the same).

Comment: @Allan - I meant the edit should add to the answer as nohillside did